# Angular UI Router running footer function when navigating to a state with no footer

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building an Angular 1.x app, using ui-router.  When I navigate to state 'a', the header, content, and footer load properly.  When I navigate away to state 'b', footer.getLabel is running after the 'b' content loads, even though that state doesn't have a ui-view for footer.  Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/rsmclaug/vhrh0av5/

index.html snippet

```
<header ui-view="header"></header>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
<footer ui-view="footer"></footer>
```

routing config snippet

```
.state('a', {
    url: '/a',
    views: {
        header: {
            templateUrl: '/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderController',
            controllerAs: 'header'
        },
        content: {
            templateUrl: '/content.html',
            controller: 'ContentController',
            controllerAs: 'content'
        },
        footer: {
            templateUrl: '/footer.html',
            controller: 'FooterController',
            controllerAs: 'footer'
        }
    }
})
.state('b', {
    url: '/b',
    views: {
        header: {
            templateUrl: '/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderController',
            controllerAs: 'header'
        },
        content: {
            templateUrl: '/content.html',
            controller: 'ContentController',
            controllerAs: 'content'
        },
        footer: {}
    }
});
```

footer.html snippet

```
<button>{{footer.getLabel()}}</button>
```

footer.js snippet

```
footer.getLabel = function(){
    // Executes when arriving at state 'b' from 'a'
};
```

Comment: JSFiddle link you added has nested states compared to the code pasted above. Based on the documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views When the application is in a particular state—when a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well. Below, when the "contacts.list" state is active, the "contacts" state is implicitly active as well, because it's the parent state to "contacts.list".
Child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view.

Comment: Based on the jsfiddle code, The test footer is executed for each of the nested views test.a and test.b

Comment: Ah, ok cool, that makes sense.  So the logging behavior that I'm seeing was coming from the parent.  That would explain why I was seeing it twice for 'a' route in the fiddle, thanks!

Comment: @prashanth so I removed the parent/child relationship between all the routes and am still seeing the same behavior.  I've created a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rsmclaug/nk9m59t3/